# popUp video youtube

Tags: javascript

Al descargar el código de esta plantilla: 
http://www.tooplate.com/view/2083-steak-house , se pierde el enlace con youtube y sale la ventana emergente en negro. (Me imagino que falta algo en el repositorio)

he revisado los js: custom.js , jquery.magnific.popup.js, que intuyo es donde está la solución, pero no lo veo.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir los mensajes de error (si alguno) que haya en la consola de JavaScript? También sería útil si pudieras compartir el código de tu página (o un [mcve]); es muy difícil ver un problema sin ver el código.

Comment: No sale ningún error, simplemente la pantalla en negro. Si descargas el repositorio de http://www.tooplate.com/view/2083-steak-house e intentas abrir el popup(video) desde el index, verás como no puedes, sin embargo, en live view se ve perfectamente. Lo que necesito saber, es como se implementa el popup en esta misma plantilla. Espero haberme explicado.